# Delphi, importing Excel files, undeclared identifier

Tags: excel, delphi, import, undeclared-identifier

I'm following the [tutorial](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa090903a.htm) on About.com on importing Excel files to Delphi. When I try to compile the file I keep on getting an error message about undeclared identifier. To my knowledge the form is names and available in the project as it should be. I will appreciate any suggestions on fixing this error.

```
unit sample_map;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB,
  Vcl.AppEvnts, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.DBCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  UWebGMapsCommon, System.Generics.Collections, UWebGMaps;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    Button1: TButton;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    ApplicationEvents1: TApplicationEvents;
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ApplicationEvents1Exception(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);

  private
  procedure TForm1.FetchData;
    begin
      StatusBar1.SimpleText:='';
      ConnectToExcel;
      AdoQuery1.Close;
      AdoQuery1.SQL.Text:=Edit2.Text;
        try
          AdoQuery1.Open;
        except
        ShowMessage('Unable to read data from Excel,
                 make sure the query ' + Edit1.Text +
                 ' is meaningful!');
        raise;
    end;
  end;

  public
    { Public declarations }

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}



procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Exception(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
  StatusBar1.SimpleText := E.Message;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  openDialog : TOpenDialog;    // Open dialog variable
  strConn : WideString; // Declare wide string for the connection
  FileName: string;

begin
  // Create the open dialog object - assign to our open dialog variable
  openDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(self);

  // Set up the starting directory to be the current one
  openDialog.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;

  // Only allow existing files to be selected
  openDialog.Options := [ofFileMustExist];

  // Allow only .Excel and .pas files to be selected
  openDialog.Filter :=
    'Excel 2003|*.xls|Excel 2007 and older|*.xlsx';

  // Select pascal files as the starting filter type
  openDialog.FilterIndex := 2;

  // Procedure to read the Excel file
  FileName := '';
  if PromptForFileName(FileName,                          // Chosen filename holder
                      'Excel 2003 and older|*.xls|Excel 2007 and older|*.xlsx',  // Filter(s) (optional)
                      '.xlsx',                            // Default extension (opt)
                      'Choose file',                     // Dialog title (opt)
                      GetCurrentDir,                     // Initial dir (opt)
                      False) then                        // Is it a save dlg? (opt)
  begin
    strConn := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;' +
               'Data Source=' + FileName + ';' +
               'Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;';
    // Connect the Excel file
    AdoConnection1.Connected:=False;
    AdoConnection1.ConnectionString:=strConn;

    // Insert the file name to the dialog box and so forth
    Edit1.Text := FileName;

    // Ad worksheets to the combo box

  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Dialog cancelled.');

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdoConnection1.LoginPrompt := False;
  AdoQuery1.Connection       := AdoConnection1;
  DataSource1.DataSet        := AdoQuery1;
  DBGrid1.DataSource         := DataSource1;
  DBNavigator1.DataSource    := DataSource1;


end;

end.
```

Comment: What identifier is the compiler is saying is undeclared?

Comment: Apparently it's **TForm1**

Comment: It's _procedure TForm1.FetchData;_, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have placed the implementation of `TForm1.FetchData` in the wrong place. It cannot be placed in the class declaration. It must be in the implementation section of the unit. Your code should look like this:

```
interface

....

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    .... // IDE fields here
  private
    procedure FetchData;
  end;

....

implementation

....

procedure TForm1.FetchData;
begin
  .... body of function here
end;
```

The tutorial that you link to contains a complete unit. I suggest that you compare the code in that complete unit with the code that you have produced.

Comment: It worked but it seems that there is another error. The compiler returns: **[dcc32 Error] sample_map.pas(43): E2029 '=' expected but 'END' found** after the public declaration.

Comment: Clearly you have another problem with your code. Remember that we cannot any longer see your code. The answer I wrote is the answer to the question that you asked. As for your new problem, please to try to debug it. Why would the compiler expect `=` instead of `end`? You can see the code. What do you think?

Comment: David, thank you for your comments. It's working know, I had number of small errors in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have included the implementation of a method in the interface section. Correct the interface section so it reads as follows :-

```
Private
  Procedure FetchData;
Public
End;
```

Then move the rest of the code down to the implementation section like this :-

```
  procedure TForm1.FetchData;
    begin
      StatusBar1.SimpleText:='';
      ConnectToExcel;
      AdoQuery1.Close;
      AdoQuery1.SQL.Text:=Edit2.Text;
        try
          AdoQuery1.Open;
        except
        ShowMessage('Unable to read data from Excel,
                 make sure the query ' + Edit1.Text +
                 ' is meaningful!');
        raise;
    end;
  end;
```